# Extract rating from web

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to scrape the top book lists in the Amazon using BeautifulSoup4, DataFrame, CSS Selectors only.

I am trying to use CSS selectors to retrieve the information. However, I am not sure how to extract each of the items like the ranking, author, book name and price.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = '        ' 
response= requests.get ('.  ')
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

container = soup.find(class_ = re.compile('a-container'))
print(container.prettify())

soup.select(" body a")
```

Comment: I feel like you're going to have to use selenium to achieve this.

Comment: Could you write some more code to show that you tried on all parts of the problem already? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Due to the small amount of code / examples in your question, just a hint how to approach the first part. no one will give you a complete solution if it is not already obvious in the question that you have dealt with the subject in depth or used the search ;)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Kindle-Store/zgbs/digital-text'
html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

data = []

for x in soup.select("li.zg-item-immersion"):
    item = {}
    try:
        item['rating'] = x.select_one('a>i').get_text().split(' ')[0]
    except:
        item['rating'] = float("NaN")
    
    item['name'] = x.select_one('a').get_text(strip=True)
    #...
    data.append(item)
        
data
```